# how to export adobe animate CC fla to illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-animate

I am trying to export an adobe animate CC file to illustrator CC. I have googled but they tell you to export as SVG. I haven't got that option and I have the latest 2017 release. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was told to go to publish settings and tick the svg box and not use the normal export as image.